# Mathematica FindInstance[] gives wrong answer

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to use Mathematica to verify that the following function

`V[x1_, x2_, u1_, u2_] = 1.494*u1^2 - 2.094 10^-24*u1 + 1.494*u2^2 - 3.988*u2 + 1.994*x2^2 - 7.333 10^-24*x2 + 2.494`

is positive definite with constraint `u1^2+u2^2==1`.

`Reduce[ForAll[{x1, x2, u1, u2}, u1^2 + u2^2 == 1, V[x1, x2, u1, u2] >= 0], {x1, x2, u1, u2}, Reals]`

returns False. But searching for the counter-example

`cex = FindInstance[u1^2 + u2^2 == 1 && V[x1, x2, u1, u2] < 0, {x1, x2, u1, u2}, Reals]
V[x1, x2, u1, u2] /. cex`

gives

`{{x1 -> 0.2, x2 -> 0, u1 -> 5.16988*10^-25, u2 -> 1.}}
 {2.22045*10^-16}`

So, Mathematica appears to contradict itself. What mistake am I making?

Comment: It appears that your mistake is assuming that decimal approximate calculations will give you exactly correct results. Any time you have a collection of numbers with only 3 digits of precision and the result turns out to be something times 10^-16 that almost always means floating point approximation errors. Try replacing all the decimal numbers with exact rational numbers and do the calculation again.

Comment: you are *also* combining `Reduce` and `ForAll` incorrectly.  Look in the docs they have `ForAll` with some extra parameters and use `Reduce` to obtain conditions on the parameters to make the for *ALL* statement true. Here your `ForAll` is simply false and `Reduce` cant do anything to change that.

Comment: @Bill I think you have it right. After rationalizing `V`, `FindInstance` actually produces a point where V is negative. Thank you!

Comment: @agentp It looks like I should have been using `Resolve` but `Reduce` will still give the right answer. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one approach here: make the expression exact. ( you should check i got this right )

```
exp=1494/1000*u1^2 - 2094 10^-27*u1 + 1494/1000*u2^2 - 3988/1000*u2 + 
 1994/1000*x2^2 - 7333 10^-27*x2 + 2494/1000
```

now we can find an exact minimum:

```
min = Minimize[{exp, u1^2 + u2^2 == 1}, {u1, u2, x2}] // Simplify //First
```

> [image]

this is negative:

```
min<0
```

> True

however it is a very small negative value:

```
N[min, 20]
```

> -7.2915903961885656971*10^-48

My guess would be the original expression is constructed to have a zero minimum and the constants are not given to sufficient precision.
Example to make it zero the last constant needs to be

> 2.4940000000000000000000000000000000000000000000072915903961..

Although given that you have coefficients on the order 10^-24, maybe that is significant.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly right. This is a numerical approximation to a Lyapunov function. Truncating the 10^-27 terms also makes it positive definite, though I have not checked that it's still zero at the equilibrium. Rationalizing the constants was also Bill's suggestion.